# Assign a color to VectorPlot

Tags: graphics, color

I want to set all the lines in a VectorPlot a specific color, like Red. I am using some of the new options for VectorPlot as my code below illustrates. Using VectorColorFunction -> Red does not solve my problem.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
VectorPlot[{1, t - x}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> 1.2, 
VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0], VectorColorFunction -> Red]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
VectorPlot[{1, t - x}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
 VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> 1.2, VectorStyle -> Red, 
 VectorMarkers -> "Segment", VectorColorFunction -> None]
```

[image]

- `VectorColorFunction -> None` to not color the vectors by magnitude
- `VectorStyle -> Red` to set the color
- `VectorMarkers -> "Segment` to just get lines

(As an alternative to using `VectorMarkers`, you could also use `VectorStyle -> Directive[Red, Arrowheads[0]]`.)

Answer (score 6):

Replace `Red` with `(Red &)` in your code to get the desired result:

```
 VectorPlot[{1, t - x}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> 1.2, 
  VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0], VectorColorFunction -> (Red &)]
```

[image]

From [`VectorColorFunction >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorColorFunction.html):

[image]

[image]

So to get *a constant function that returns `Red` for all arguments* we need to use `Red&` The parentheses in `VectorColorFunction -> (Red &)` is added because without parentheses this expression would be parsed as  `(VectorColorFunction -> Red) &`.

Answer (score 1):

The following example comes from the help of `D` entry:

```
   ClearAll["Global`*"]
    v[x_, y_] := {1, x - y}
    curl[{x_, y_}] = D[x + y, x] - D[x^2 y, y];
    Manipulate[
     VectorPlot[v[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
      Epilog -> {If[curl[s] > 0, Green, Red], Thick, Dashed, Point[s], 
        Circle[s, Abs[curl[s]/3]]}], {{s, {0, 0}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}, 
     SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

We can also specify multiple display colors by condition:

```
    f[x_, y_] := Evaluate[Curl[{1, x - y}, {x, y}]]
StreamPlot[{1, x - y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] /. {Arrowheads[spec_], 
   Arrow[pts_]} :> {Arrowheads[
    0.01*Abs[
      f[pts[[1, 1]], 
       pts[[1, 2]]]]], {If[(x - y /. {x -> pts[[1, 1]], 
         y -> pts[[1, 2]]}) > 0, Red, Black], Arrow[pts]}}
```

Or

```
VectorPlot[{1, t - x}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
 VectorScaling -> False, VectorSizes -> 1.2, 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> 
  False(*this option must be set to false*), 
 VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0], 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, vx, vy, r}, 
    If[x > 0 && y > 0, Red, Black]])]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116305/discussion-on-answer-by-a-little-mouse-on-the-pampas-assign-a-color-to-vectorplo).

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. I'm just joking with my acquaintances. Because my native language is not English, maybe there will be errors in the expression of tone. I won't do it next time.